# How to get samsung moment to connect with adb

Tags: android

I am trying to get my samsung moment (android 2.1) connected to my windows 7 64bit desktop so that I can debug on phone from the netbeans ide.

In my phone settings I have Settings > Applications > Development > USB Debugging checked
I read that Settings > About phone > Additional Settings > Mass store, should not be checked but I don't have an additional settings item in the about phone section

I have the android sdk downloaded and unzipped along with the usb drivers downloaded through the sdk manager.

When I plug the phone in windows says it cant find the drivers.  When I goto device manager I see SAMSUNG_Android listed under Other devices.  When I hit update drivers and point it at the android-sdk-windows\usb_driver folder it says "Windows could not find driver software for your device"

running adb devices on the command prompt only lists the virtual device emulator i setup.

running adb kill-server prior to adb devices doesnt have any effect.

Any ideas?

p.s.  If I turn off usb debugging and connect the usb to the computer, it recognizes the sd card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a youtube clip that lays it out fairly well:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CS6Hkdow2Hk#

Live debugging doesnt seem to work, but I'm not sure if its supposed to